# Apply conditional formatting to many rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a data validation set up for a list to choose from (B7:B1000), only two words can be selected: `PP` or `SW`. I have figured out a conditional format to fill the row if `PP` is selected but I need to apply this to the whole spreadsheet. I am having to apply conditional formatting for every row and it's time consuming if I need to do this for 1,000 rows.

I selected *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*. This is what I currently have it set up as:

```
=B7="PP" conditional formatting to be applied to =$F$7:$N$7
```

I now need to do this for all rows in the spreadsheet:

```
=B8="PP" conditional formatting to be applied to =$F$8:$N$8  
=B9="PP" conditional formatting to be applied to =$F$9:$N$9  
=B10="PP" conditional formatting to be applied to =$F$10:$N$10
```

and so on.

Is there a quicker way rather than manually doing this for 1,000 rows?

I have tried the format painter but its just copies the previous formula. Tried removing the `$` symbols but when I click `Apply` they are re-inserted.

Comment: I meant the $ dollar symbol not the & symbol

Comment: Please edit your question to apply corrections, do not use a comment for that.

Comment: did not know you could do that. new to this site. Thanks

Comment: When you set the conditional formatting select the entire column(s) you want adjusted. Use the same formula just reference the first row of the column. Excel will figure it out from there.

Comment: I tried that but it only wants to condition format one cell even though i have selected several cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Title makes me wonder whether you would like some formatting for `SW` as well as `PP` but guessing you don't then in Row7 please try:

```
=$B7="PP"
```

for the CF formula and make sure `Applies to` shows `=$A$7:$Z$1000` - or whatever column reference you choose in place of Z.

Comment: That worked! When i selected the F9:N100 cells manually it only formats one cell F9.